# Install El-Capitan from bootable USB asks me to enter Apple ID but nothing happen

Tags: macos, install, apple-id

I'm installing El Capitan on my MacBook Pro (mid 2012) from bootable USB.

The original OS of my Mac is Lion and the latest OS is High Sierra, so I created a bootable flash drive for El-Capitan.

The installation process asks me to enter an Apple ID.If I I enter it correctly dialog close and nothing happens!

I enter wrong Apple ID to check whether my internet connection is ok or not and does it really check my password or not.
When I enter my password wrong it prompts me, so the Internet connection is OK.

I searched a lot but found nothing, what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: And you know as everyone that on "normal case" when you install on an USB this is in a case where you don't have any Internet connection. This isn't the case here, and if you don't clarify your question you will most probably get stupid questions as mine, or nothing at all.

Comment: @danielAzuelos What do you mean? of course, I have an internet connection, the installation process from USB also need the internet connection. I don't know why, but it needs anyway

Comment: Why don't you install without internet connection?

Comment: @PratikaRana Installation process ask me to connect to the internet

Comment: @HamedGh : why did you enter a wrong password to validate your Apple Id?

Comment: @danielAzuelos to show that internet connection is OK!

Comment: @danielAzuelos Did you understand what is my problem?? I said it ask me to enter Apple ID, if I I enter it correctly dialog close and nothing happen!!! I just enter wrong Apple ID to check whether my internet connection is ok or not and does it really check my password or not!